# How to put input file automatically in hdfs?

Tags: hdfs

In Hadoop we always putting input file manually through -put command. Is there any way we can automate this process ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated process of inputing a file into the Hadoop filesystem. However, it is possible to -put or -get multiple files with one command.

Here is the website for the Hadoop shell commands
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many files you are dropping into HDFS, but one solution for watching for files and then dropping them in is Apache Flume. [These slides](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/clouderas-flume) provide a decent intro.

Comment: Hi Matt, I m getting every minute a new file and theses files are very small in size so i have to merge these files and sent to hdfs for every half an hour interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can thing of automatic this process with Fabric library and python. Write hdfs put command in a function and you can call it for multiple file and perform same operations of multiple hosts in network. Fabric should be really helpful to automate in your scenario.